# Postgresql: The most efficient query for selecting "the highest lower" and "all higher"

Tags: sql, database, performance, postgresql

Let's have a database table, e. g.:

```
t_times (id INTEGER, created TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE);
```

Is there a possibility to write a query that would return all entries created after the given date and the latest entry created before given date?

It is simply possible with UNION, but isn't there any faster way?

```
SELECT * FROM t_times WHERE created >= ?
UNION
SELECT * FROM t_times WHERE created < ? ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: `union all` is faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`union all` is faster:

```
(SELECT * FROM t_times WHERE created >= ?)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM t_times WHERE created < ? ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1);
```

This may be a bit faster with an index on `created`:

```
select t.*
from t_times t
where t.created >= (select max(t2.created) from t_times where t2.created < ?);
```

The idea is that the index would be used for the subquery . . . very fast.  And then the index is used for fetching the rows.  However, this would only be a slight improvement on the query with `union all`.

Comment: You're right, that UNION ALL is faster.But of course it was not the main point. The second select that you provided does not return exactly same result everytime (notice the LIMIT 1 in the original query, but is very useful for me). Anyway, thank you for your answer.